# math.fsum for arrays of multiple dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension `(i, j)` in which I would like to add up the first dimension to receive a array of shape `(j,)`. Normally, I'd use NumPy's own [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(100, 77)
numpy.sum(a, axis=0)
```

but in my case it doesn't cut it: Some of the sums are *very* ill-conditioned, so the computed results only have a few correct digits.

[`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) is fantastic at keeping the errors at bay, but it only applies to iterables of one dimension. [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) doesn't do the job either.

How to efficiently apply `math.fsum` to an array of multiply dimensions?

Comment: not sure if i have understood the question , but have you looked at this?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi Doesn't help: I need summation over a dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works fast enough for me.

```
import numpy
import math

a = numpy.random.rand(100, 77)
a = numpy.swapaxes(a, 0, 1)
a = numpy.array([math.fsum(row) for row in a])
```

Hopefully it's the axis you are looking for (returns 77 sums).

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis(math.fsum, 0, a)` also works, but has more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `signature` keyword to [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

```
_math_fsum_vec = numpy.vectorize(math.fsum, signature='(m)->()')
```

Unfortunately, it's slower than the `for` solution:

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import math
import numpy
import perfplot


_math_fsum_vec = numpy.vectorize(math.fsum, signature='(m)->()')


def fsum_vectorize(a):
    return _math_fsum_vec(a.T).T


def fsum_for(a):
    return numpy.array([math.fsum(row) for row in a.T])


perfplot.save(
    'fsum.png',
    setup=lambda n: numpy.random.rand(n, 100),
    kernels=[fsum_vectorize, fsum_for],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(12)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    )
```